# ApacheTop and Plesk

Tags: apache-2.2, performance, logging

I am trying to find a way to monitor my apache server so I can see which domain is causing slow down on my server when they occur.  I was hoping I would be able to do it with ApacheTop but I have to list our each log file separately as Plesk splits domains apache logs into individual files.

Is there a way I can do this with ApacheTop or should I be using another tool?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

this script monitors your apache - cron it with */5 and configure it
http://www.triologic.eu/apache-monitor.0.html?&L=1
triologic web-team

Answer (score 1):

Quite manual best the best way I have found so far.

Attach multiple domain access logs to the same apachetop process, and get a total overview of whats happening in real time. You can specific multiple access logs using this syntax :

```
apachetop -f /var/www/vhosts/site1.com/statistics/logs/access_log -f /var/www/vhosts/site2.com/statistics/logs/access_log -f /var/www/vhosts/site3.com/statistics/logs/access_log -f /var/www/vhosts/site4.com/statistics/logs/access_log -f /var/www/vhosts/site5.com/statistics/logs/access_log
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping someone would come up with a fancy way to tracking domains down.  The method I've been using is to enable mod_fcgid and make all PHP sites run under it.  This means that PHP scripts using a lot of CPU time show up in the process table & top.  Also I check the mysql processlist to see sites that have databases and if they are also using a lot of CPU time.

Would be great if there was another way of tracking down CPU hog sites.

I suppose you could possibly use ApacheTop by making a custom log rule in the apache configuration file to log all sites to a single access_log.  This should be possible without affecting the normal logging of the sites.

Hoping someone has a better solution though.